# SSH connection Lost after switch accessmode vlan *

Tags: ssh, connection, cisco, switching, vlan

When I attempt to assign a port (say Gi1-2) to a vlan other than vlan 1, the SSH connection is lost upon firing the switchport access vlan command.
I have created 2 VLANs (10,20) in addition to the default vlan 1. The PC I am using to access the switch is connected to Gi10. When I try to assign that port to one of the vlan’s (say vlan 10), the connection locks up.
Here are the commands I am using
Switch# configure terminal
Switch(config)# interface range Gi1-2
Switch(config-if)# switchport mode access
Switch(config-if)# switchport access vlan 10
<<--- terminal doesn’t respond anymore ---->>

Before configuring the same, vlan 1 (default vlan) is assigned with an ip address (192.168.1.254).

After this if I try to connect to the switch via SSH, the switch is no longer seen on the network from this PC.
If I switch the cable to another port, then I can connect to it. So, I am assuming that since the ports are on Vlan 1, they are accessible via SSH.
Also tried this under telnet, with the same results.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean when you say you create vlan 10 and 20, do you assign them IP address ? you understand that vlan and int vlan are 2 different things. SVI is a logical interface where as vlan logical network (broadcast doamin)